# Bootstrap Custom Search to Search Google

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-search, search-box

I'm having trouble trying to get my search to work. I would like to just have my search text box search google and then go to google search display. I don't need it to search my site at all. Only need to search google from my site using my search box. I'm not very familiar with using a custom search so please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-left searchBarFix">
    <input type="text" data-provider="https://www.google.com" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Our Games..." autocomplete="on" id="searchInput">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the Google Search API?

The API is very robust, and it sounds like it will do exactly what you're looking for.

https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/

Although that solution is deprecated, so you may want to look into Google's Custom Search Engine.

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/start